# How do I manipulate where the Skeleton King teleports?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

In attempting to get [Instant Karma](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63509/how-do-i-get-the-instant-karma-achievement), I died a few times on my Wizard then gave up figuring I was too low level to tank incidental damage, though I did get close (12/15).  My major problem was trying to get him to teleport near his minions so he would flail about and knock them to pieces.

His teleport sometimes seems to follow the path his ghostly essence is moving as he casts it—I was thinking it was essentially an invisible straight-line charge—but other times he goes way off and pops out right on me.  Does he commit to landing at a certain spot before the effect appears (can't move very far to reposition between that and him popping out)?  Is there a range limit/angular limit to it I can <strike>ab</strike>use?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking the wrong question for how to get the Instant Karma achievement. You don't really need him to teleport to any specific place at all. Instead, you need him to do his big ghostly swing ability (during which he is invulnerable) into a pack of minions.

You can do this by staying pretty close to him (which you understandably won't be doing much of if you're a Wizard). The minions will come closer to you, which is closer to him. Then, when he chuckles to take his big swing, dodge away. His direction is pretty set when he begins his swinging, and he should take out several of the the minions for you.

I believe you need to repeat this 2-3 times. Fortunately, the minions dying will give you health globes.  You may also want to consider taking some damage reducing abilities, like [Diamond Skin](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/diamond-skin), for when you're standing near him or as he starts swinging.

Answer (score 0):

I got Instant Karma without knowing about it on a WD; haven't done it on a Wizard (don't really bother with Achievements). Based on my experience fighting him, I think it should be fairly easy if you are close to his minions when he teleports to you (as SK often does his swing soon after a teleport).

I'd recommend running away from him (which you will do a lot as a Wizard anyway). When you barely see him on screen, he will likely teleport to you soon just to be a pest ... so stop kiting the small fry, and instead go near them (if you use frost nova might want to freeze them right as he starts teleport, so you can try to run away while he is doing the swing)

If you can draw away from him and kite the skeletons into a group, it should be much easier to kill several of them at a time, so long as you can time it right before Leoric goes after you.